Why does my integration test not work in Angular 19?
Just having a simple navbar component with 4 links : Login & Signup (if not logged in), My Account & Logout (if logged in). I wrote an integration test to check if the click on the logout link calls the logout method.
Here is the navbar.component.html :
<nav class="navbar">
    <a routerLink="/" class="logo">E-Market</a>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a routerLink="/products">Products</a></li>
      <li id="login" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"><a routerLink="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
      <li id="sign-up" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"><a routerLink="/auth/sign-up">Sign up</a></li>
      <li id="account" *ngIf="isLoggedIn"><a routerLink="/account">My account</a></li>
      <li id="logout" *ngIf="isLoggedIn"><a  (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  

Here is the navbar.component.ts :
import { Component, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss'],
    standalone: false
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  isLoggedIn!: boolean;
  
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    effect(() => {
      this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    });
  }
  
  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}

Here is the navbar.component.spec.ts :
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
  let authServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<AuthService>;
  let routerSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    authServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthService', ['isLoggedIn', 'logout']);
    routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigateByUrl']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NavbarComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceSpy },
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should call logout method when clicking on "Logout"', () => {
    authServiceSpy.isLoggedIn.and.returnValue(true);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component, 'logout').and.callThrough();;

    const logoutLink = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#logout');
    logoutLink.click();
    expect(component.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(authServiceSpy.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(routerSpy.navigateByUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/');
  });
});

And when I run the tests, I get this answer:

Chrome 131.0.0.0 (Windows 10) NavbarComponent should call logout method when clicking on "Logout" FAILED
Expected spy logout to have been called.
at 
at UserContext.apply (src/app/navbar/components/navbar/navbar.component.spec.ts:67:30)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:369:28)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2082:39)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:368:34)
Expected spy AuthService.logout to have been called.
at 
at UserContext.apply (src/app/navbar/components/navbar/navbar.component.spec.ts:68:35)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:369:28)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2082:39)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:368:34)
Expected spy Router.navigateByUrl to have been called with:
[ '/' ]
but it was never called.
at 
at UserContext.apply (src/app/navbar/components/navbar/navbar.component.spec.ts:69:37)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:369:28)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2082:39)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:368:34)

I tried to edit the integration test but it always fails. Also I've tested the functionality on the browser, and the click on the logout anchor works as expected so I understand that the problem is in the test code.
ChatGPT can't help me either.

The problem is you are clicking the li tag and not the a tag where the click event is present.
const logoutLink = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#logout > a'));
logoutLink.nativeElement.click();

Or, we can set the click event on the li tag:
<li id="logout" (click)="logout()"><a>Logout</a></li>

I prefer the second fix, because li tag will have a larger clickable area better for user experience.
